# HasOne through two ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my `Part` model, I have this:

```
    public function inv(): hasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Inv::class)->where([
          ['user_id', $this->user_id],
          ['survey_id', $this->survey_id]
        ]);
    }
```

which returns :
`local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column invs.part_id does not exist`

`Part` and `Inv` models both have `user_id` and `survey_id`, and there's always a part for an inv. How can I change this code to get the inv corresponding to a part, and be able to load like this `->with('inv')` ?

Comment: It's normal to have that error, the `hasOne` check if in your `Inv` model there is a `part_id` column

Comment: Try to use `HasOneThrough` using `survey_id` and add another one with `->where('user_id','=', $this->user_id);`

Comment: @Maraboc it doesn't work because there's no `user_id` in the intermediary survey model

Comment: I have tackled this problem once before by using [compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships), but it does come with a performance cost (short way). I basically dropped it and customized eloquent's default relation handlers and replaced them where I needed (long way).